# why is CSS font-size change droping text a little?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button, and in the button, I have the text "**More About Us**".
`<button class="more_about_btn"><b>More About Us</b></button>`
When a mouse hovers over the button I want the button to increase the font size. That works.. the problem I am having is that the text is moving down a little after the transition ends. Here is an example of what is happening.

```css
.more_about_btn {
  background-color: #3c78d8;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}

.more_about_btn:hover {
  font-size: 19px;
}
```

```html
<button class="more_about_btn"><b>More About Us</b></button>
```

I just want a smooth transition where the text increases in size slowly as long as the person has there mouse over the button. I kinda want to stick with CSS, but if there is a way with JS that is smoother, that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

***Hi***,

This is hapeen because of `margin-top: 100px`

See What happen if `margin-top` not exist

```css
.more_about_btn {
  background-color: #3c78d8;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}

.more_about_btn:hover {
  font-size: 19px;
}
```

```html
<button class="more_about_btn"><b>More About Us</b></button>
```

Or Just Replace `font-size` with `transform: scale()`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `font-size` with `transform: scale()`:

```css
    .more_about_btn {
      background-color: #3c78d8;
      border: none;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 60%;
      height: 35px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #fff;
      margin-top: 100px;
      font-size: 18px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transform: scale(0);
      transition: transform 2s linear;
    }

    .more_about_btn:hover {
      transform: scale(0.2);
    }
```

```html
    <button class="more_about_btn"><b>More About Us</b></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the margin-top. This occurs because the size of the font changes and it is needed to change the padding too *padding-bottom:9px*;

```css
.more_about_btn {
  background-color: #3c78d8;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}

.more_about_btn:hover {
  font-size: 19px;
  padding-bottom:9px;
}
```

```html
<button class="more_about_btn"><b>More About Us</b></button>
```